# Stop cycling carousels after playing video in carousel [IE]

Tags: javascript, html, video, carousel

I want the carousels to stop cycling after the video is played, but also when it is paused or the video ended, the cycling should resume. This code is working in most browsers except IE, but I can't figure out how to make it work even in IE, do you have any ideas?

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hellk</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amethysta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Start Video Section -->
    <div class="clip-container">
        <h1><span class="fire">K</span>
            <span class="burn">L</span>
            <span class="burn">I</span>
            <span class="fire">P</span>
            <span class="fire">Y</span>
        </h1>
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause=>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <iframe id="player1" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1RHSrSVcPGI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player2" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6KRlz9ZTpbw?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player3" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/meRKYpo6W7A?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player4" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JFJwZDSJrUo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player5" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TV4EFQNJuOo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player6" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5cZ1HC-wFeo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Video Section -->
    <script>
        const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu');
        let menuOpen = false;
        menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (!menuOpen) {
                menuBtn.classList.add('open');
                menuOpen = true;
            } else {
                menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
                menuOpen = false;
            }
        });

        menuBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            menuBtn.classList.add('hover');
            menuHover = true;
        });
        menuBtn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            menuBtn.classList.remove('hover');
            menuHover = true;
        });

        function menuClose() {
            document.querySelector('.menu').classList.remove('open');
            menuOpen = false;
        }
        const mychat = document.getElementById('chat');
        const mychaticon = document.getElementById('chat-icon');
        let chatn = false;

        mychaticon.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (chatn == false) {
                mychat.style.transition = '1.5s';
                mychat.style.opacity = '1';
                mychat.style.visibility = 'visible';
                chatn = true;
                $(".chat-icon").addClass('clicked');
            } else {
                mychat.style.opacity = '0';
                mychat.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                chatn = false;
                $(".chat-icon").removeClass('clicked');
            }
        });
        mychaticon.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            mychaticon.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            $(".chat-icon").addClass('change');
        });
        mychaticon.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            mychaticon.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
            $(".chat-icon").removeClass('change');
        });

        function topFunction() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }
        var mybutton = document.getElementById("scroll");


        window.onscroll = function() {
            scrollFunction()
        };

        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                mybutton.style.opacity = "1";
                mybutton.style.visibility = "visible";
            } else {
                mybutton.style.opacity = "0";
                mybutton.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('scroll').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            document.getElementById('scroll').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.6)";
        });
        document.getElementById('scroll').addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            document.getElementById('scroll').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.25)";
        });

        function onStateChange(event) {
            var embedCode = event.target.getVideoEmbedCode();
            event.target.playVideo();
            if (document.getElementById('embed-code')) {
                document.getElementById('embed-code').innerHTML = embedCode;
            }
        }

        var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player1', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player2', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player3', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player4', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player5', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player6', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            switch (event.data) {
                case 0:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('cycle');
                    console.log("End");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('pause');
                    console.log("Start");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('cycle');
                    console.log("Pause");
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <!--- Script Source Files -->
    <script src="js/rellax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <!--- End of Script Source Files -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');

        const clipScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.carousel.slide');
        clipScroll.forEach((iframe) => {
            ScrollTrigger.create({
                trigger: iframe,
                toggleClass: 'scroll',
                start: "top 85%",
                end: "end -50%"
            })
        });
        const streamScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.stream');
        streamScroll.forEach((iframe) => {
            ScrollTrigger.create({
                trigger: iframe,
                toggleClass: 'scroll',
                start: "top 80%",
                end: "end -70%"
            })
        });
        const chatScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.chat-icon');
        chatScroll.forEach((span) => {
            ScrollTrigger.create({
                trigger: span,
                toggleClass: 'scroll',
                start: "top 100%",
                end: "end 20%"
            })
        });
        const linksScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.links');
        linksScroll.forEach((div) => {
            ScrollTrigger.create({
                trigger: div,
                toggleClass: 'scroll',
                start: "top 50%",
                end: "end -15%"
            })
        });
        const linksBgScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.links-bg');
        linksBgScroll.forEach((div) => {
            ScrollTrigger.create({
                trigger: div,
                toggleClass: 'scroll',
                start: "top 90%",
                end: "end 10%"
            })
        });
        const voteScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.vote-container');
        voteScroll.forEach((span) => {
            ScrollTrigger.create({
                trigger: span,
                toggleClass: 'scroll',
                start: "top 80%",
                end: "end -10%"
            })
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</body>

</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Here is the script part which I'm using to find out in which state is video (playing, paused, ended)

```
var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player1', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player2', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player3', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player4', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player5', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player6', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            switch (event.data) {
                case 0:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('cycle');
                    console.log("End");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('pause');
                    console.log("Start");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('cycle');
                    console.log("Pause");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I'm also beginner, so I'm prety much sure this code can be written in smaller scale, but I want to know which code does what and then I can start to shrink code up with some tricks.

Website: https://hellk.funsite.cz/

Comment: Please share entire codebase such as script and CSS URL's you are using. Need at least reproducible example.

Comment: You can see the example on my website: https://hellk.funsite.cz/

Comment: Which version of IE you are using. I can see it is getting stopped and resumes once we play video in IE11

Comment: I'm using IE11, but I just tried it again and when I play the video the carousel keep cycling.

Comment: I can see few JS errors related to rellax JS and menu button handler once I try to run your code in local. Once I commented that It is working fine in IE 11.

Comment: I didn't post my whole code here and I even removed rellax js now, cuz I'm not using it anymore and still nothing changes, but maybe it's just me. Because in my ie, console doesn't show anything.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz example?

Comment: I can't, the files are too big to upload it to github and from there to stackblitz. But like I said there are no errors, just sometimes they pop up, because twitch doesn't response and then they are few warning with cross-site cookies, but they don't really do much.

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on the video, YT player takes some time to load and play the video. Meanwhile before playing video carousel is moving to next slide. You can prevent that behavior by using one more switch case event.data = -1 parameter inside **onPlayerStateChange** method.

```js
 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            switch (event.data) {
                // pause carousel when video is about to load
                case -1: 
                   $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('pause');
                   break;
                case 0:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('cycle');
                    console.log("End");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('pause');
                    console.log("Start");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('cycle');
                    console.log("Pause");
                    break;
            }
 }
```

I have tried commenting the code for rellax JS and menu button as It is throwing errors in the console. For IE11 to work you must clear the console errors first.
Try executing below code in your local and check IE11.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hellk</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amethysta' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Start Video Section -->
    <div class="clip-container">
        <h1><span class="fire">K</span>
            <span class="burn">L</span>
            <span class="burn">I</span>
            <span class="fire">P</span>
            <span class="fire">Y</span>
        </h1>
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause=>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <iframe id="player1" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1RHSrSVcPGI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player2" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6KRlz9ZTpbw?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player3" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/meRKYpo6W7A?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player4" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JFJwZDSJrUo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player5" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TV4EFQNJuOo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <iframe id="player6" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5cZ1HC-wFeo?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Video Section -->
    <script>
        /*
        const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu');
        let menuOpen = false;
        menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (!menuOpen) {
                menuBtn.classList.add('open');
                menuOpen = true;
            } else {
                menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
                menuOpen = false;
            }
        });

        menuBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            menuBtn.classList.add('hover');
            menuHover = true;
        });
        menuBtn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            menuBtn.classList.remove('hover');
            menuHover = true;
        });

        function menuClose() {
            document.querySelector('.menu').classList.remove('open');
            menuOpen = false;
        }
        const mychat = document.getElementById('chat');
        const mychaticon = document.getElementById('chat-icon');
        let chatn = false;

        mychaticon.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (chatn == false) {
                mychat.style.transition = '1.5s';
                mychat.style.opacity = '1';
                mychat.style.visibility = 'visible';
                chatn = true;
                $(".chat-icon").addClass('clicked');
            } else {
                mychat.style.opacity = '0';
                mychat.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                chatn = false;
                $(".chat-icon").removeClass('clicked');
            }
        });
        mychaticon.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            mychaticon.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            $(".chat-icon").addClass('change');
        });
        mychaticon.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            mychaticon.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
            $(".chat-icon").removeClass('change');
        });

        function topFunction() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }
        var mybutton = document.getElementById("scroll");


        window.onscroll = function() {
            scrollFunction()
        };

        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
                mybutton.style.opacity = "1";
                mybutton.style.visibility = "visible";
            } else {
                mybutton.style.opacity = "0";
                mybutton.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('scroll').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            document.getElementById('scroll').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.6)";
        });
        document.getElementById('scroll').addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            document.getElementById('scroll').style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.25)";
        });
   */
        function onStateChange(event) {
            var embedCode = event.target.getVideoEmbedCode();
            event.target.playVideo();
            if (document.getElementById('embed-code')) {
                document.getElementById('embed-code').innerHTML = embedCode;
            }
        }

        var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player1', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player2', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player3', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player4', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player5', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
            player = new YT.Player('player6', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            switch (event.data) {
                case -1: 
                   $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('pause');
                   break;
                case 0:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('cycle');
                    console.log("End");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('pause');
                    console.log("Start");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('cycle');
                    console.log("Pause");
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <!--- Script Source Files -->
    <script src="js/rellax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <!--- End of Script Source Files -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //     var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');

    //     const clipScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.carousel.slide');
    //     clipScroll.forEach((iframe) => {
    //         ScrollTrigger.create({
    //             trigger: iframe,
    //             toggleClass: 'scroll',
    //             start: "top 85%",
    //             end: "end -50%"
    //         })
    //     });
    //     const streamScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.stream');
    //     streamScroll.forEach((iframe) => {
    //         ScrollTrigger.create({
    //             trigger: iframe,
    //             toggleClass: 'scroll',
    //             start: "top 80%",
    //             end: "end -70%"
    //         })
    //     });
    //     const chatScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.chat-icon');
    //     chatScroll.forEach((span) => {
    //         ScrollTrigger.create({
    //             trigger: span,
    //             toggleClass: 'scroll',
    //             start: "top 100%",
    //             end: "end 20%"
    //         })
    //     });
    //     const linksScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.links');
    //     linksScroll.forEach((div) => {
    //         ScrollTrigger.create({
    //             trigger: div,
    //             toggleClass: 'scroll',
    //             start: "top 50%",
    //             end: "end -15%"
    //         })
    //     });
    //     const linksBgScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.links-bg');
    //     linksBgScroll.forEach((div) => {
    //         ScrollTrigger.create({
    //             trigger: div,
    //             toggleClass: 'scroll',
    //             start: "top 90%",
    //             end: "end 10%"
    //         })
    //     });
    //     const voteScroll = gsap.utils.toArray('.vote-container');
    //     voteScroll.forEach((span) => {
    //         ScrollTrigger.create({
    //             trigger: span,
    //             toggleClass: 'scroll',
    //             start: "top 80%",
    //             end: "end -10%"
    //         })
    //     });
     </script>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</body>

</html>
```